# Can I see my own name?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I know, that censorship is really weird in DS3. For example, word 'Knight' in character name becomes 'K***ht'.

I'm going to create new character with fancy name and I'm afraid that name will be censored.

Is there any way to see my character name just like other people will see it in online play? I want to quickly figure out if it's ok or not in start location.

Comment: I saw this [name censor checker](http://omgftw.github.io/DarkSouls3CensorCheck/) posted on Reddit the other day, and it seems pretty accurate. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how one checks it in-game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In-game, by yourself: No. Even if you put down your sign or check the menus, your name will show "correctly".

You can start the game, get the White Soapstone, put up a password and ask a friend to use said password and find your summon sign on an early area, such as the High Wall of Lothric, and then he can tell you how your name shows.

**However** there are external tools that do the job, such as the [Dark Souls 3 Name Check](https://omgftw.github.io/DarkSouls3CensorCheck/) by omgftw. Since the censorship file containing all censored words has been [datamined](https://github.com/omgftw/DarkSouls3CensorCheck/blob/master/censorlist.js), this checker is updated and accurate.